# Connects to database while guest, can't connect while logged in

Tags: asp.net

I got movies controller with index action, it returns view with list of my movies from database. It works perfect. List is loaded, and buttons aviable only for "admin" role are hidden thanks to this code (when i comment it, it works even if logged):

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    }
```

Than I am logging on account with "Admin" role assigned. View can't load because controller can't load films.

Work while not logged, it is how it looks like.

[image: everything works while not logged]

Not work while logged in, it is how it look like.

[image: not work while logged]

And yeaa, i know controller should not contain logic and operations on db, i will refactor it later!

Comment: You are using `User.IsInRole("Admin")`, but you say you are logging in as a user with role "admin".  Is this is a typo?  "A" != "a" in string comparisons.

Comment: "VIew can't load because..." what does this mean? are you getting exceptions?  Can you give specifics about what is not working?

Comment: What @Kritner said.  If you can post a screenshot of the error you're getting that would be very helpful. (Ideally a "yellow screen of death")

Comment: I specified wrong, role is called "Admin" so there is no problem.

Comment: can't add third image cause no reputation enought http://i.stack.imgur.com/OQaHs.png here is it, addional info says: cant connect to database mysql server in english

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a reason.

I need to configure rolemanager in webconfig.xml

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
</roleManager>
```

It is default setting. Maybe it causes error.